# Creating a real-time chat with Python and websocket

Tags: python, websocket, chat, real-time

I'm writing a python real-time chat feature embedded in a web app. I'm a little bit confused on the real time implementation. I need to push real time message to different users.

I plan to use websocket but I'm not quite sure how to save those sockets into an array so that once a user send a message to server, the server can find the related socket and push the message.

So any idea about this? Or what's the common way to implement real time chat feature?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to use a websocket aware web server, like [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/) to handle websocket traffic. To multiplex chat messages between different chats and users, there are solutions like Redis and ZeroMQ that you can use for message multiplexing.

However, it sounds like you have zero experience and starting point, so starting with an working example is better approach. Please study existing real-time chat implementations for Python:

https://github.com/heroku-examples/python-websockets-chat

https://github.com/nellessen/Tornado-Redis-Chat

https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/demos/websocket/chatdemo.py

http://ferretfarmer.net/2013/09/05/tutorial-real-time-chat-with-django-twisted-and-websockets-part-1/

Comment: As a reminder, this answer is several years outdated and there are now new Python async web servers that are more suited for the task.

Comment: for people who are looking at this now (jan 2024) you can check out [socket service](https://github.com/shashstormer/socket_service/blob/master/main.py) implementation as it implements connection with multiple clients (it is slightly complicated but with some python, async knowledge it can be understood)

Comment: Nice. I hope I had this a decade ago!